# Jquery : Overlapping Div cause triggering Div to lost focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this current issue , my current div placement is like this

```
<div class="photo-wrapper" style="positon:relative">
    <div class="img-menu" style="position:absolute">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~\Content\images\checkin.png")" />
        <br /><br />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~\Content\images\btn-login.png")"/>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar-wrap"><img src="bg.jpg"/></div>
 </div>
```

and I have a mouseover event like this

```
$(".photo-wrapper").mouseover(function () {

    //show specific password
    $(this).find('.img-menu').fadeIn('fast');
});
$(".photo-wrapper").mouseout(function () {
    $('.img-menu').each(function () { $(this).stop().css('display', 'none') });
});
```

Let say .img-menu will be on top of .photo-wrapper , and .img-menu is half of photo wrapper size . When I hover photo-wrapper , img-menu will come out . However when I move the cursor to img-menu , the mouseover even will flicker once . How do I make it to think that img-menu is part of photo-wrapper so that the hover wont lost focus ?

Comment: Try using mouseleave instead of mouseout and mouseenter instead of mouseover

Comment: Great ! It was this easy , thanks .

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(".photo-wrapper").mouserenter(function () {
    //show specific password
    $(this).find('.img-menu').fadeIn('fast');
});
$(".photo-wrapper").mouseleave(function () {
    $('.img-menu').each(function () { $(this).stop().css('display', 'none') });
});
```